# Is there any function to extract (get) a value of an attribute using bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attr

I need to extract attribute value.I was surfing the net and could not find any solutions. The only I found was to use CSS selector ('select-one'). But the problem is that I need to get ALL the values from the attribute. So here is it:

```
        <span data-name="BLABLABLA" data-id="40423" data-volume="18.643.727" class="alertBellGrayPlus js-plus-icon genToolTip    oneliner" data-tooltip="BLABLABLA"></span>
```

I need to get data-id value(it is 40423). But also there are 3 spans more. How do I get all the values, if they have these(span and data-id) in common.
I tried something like this:

```
 DataNames = soup.findAll('span',attrs = {'data-id':True} )
 for value in DataNames:
    data_names.append(value.span['data-id'])
```

Comment: Pls give us the 3 more spans in your example. You only give us one. Also, please give us your expected result.

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ They are the same but with different values like data-id = '40444" and so on. I expect it will print out these values. 40424... and others

Comment: the question has no good example and expected result. I'll pass on this. Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 DataNames = soup.findAll('span',attrs = {'data-id':True} )
 for element in DataNames:
     data_names.append(element['data-id'])
```

I didn't test it, if you post the link you're trying to get this from I think I could help you more

Comment: Can you write it more clearly. Because you just 'copy pasted' the code from other question

Comment: Yea I know and it was completely wrong, I was writing while not being logged in and when i logged it turned back to the first thing

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is still looking for a solution:

```
input="""<span data-name="BLABLABLA" data-id="40423" data-volume="18.643.727" class="alertBellGrayPlus js-plus-icon genToolTip    oneliner" data-tooltip="BLABLABLA"></span>"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(input,'html')
results = soup.find_all("span")
for result in results:
    print(result.get('data-id'))
```

The output will be:

```
40423
```